# I am developing a calculator in tkinter in python

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

The problem am facing is that the number does appear in the entry when I click the button, but when I click the next button the previous one gets deleted and the entry gets updated with the new number. I want to concatenate the numbers so that I can type the desired integer.

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Calculator")
root.geometry('300x300')
    

def num1():
    ss = 1
    link.set( ss)

def num2():
    ss = 2
    link.set(ss)

link = tk.StringVar()
entry = tk.Entry(root, width = 50 , textvariable = link).place(x = 0 , y = 20)
btn1 = tk.Button(root , height = 3 , width = 6 , text = "1", command = num1 ).place(x= 0, y = 100)
btn2 = tk.Button(root, height = 3 , width = 6 , text = "2", command = num2 ).place(x = 60 , y = 100)
btn3 = tk.Button(root, height = 3 , width = 6 , text = "3", ).place(x = 120 , y = 100)
btn4 = tk.Button(root, height = 3 , width = 6 , text = "4", ).place(x = 180 , y = 100)
btn5 = tk.Button(root, height = 3 , width = 6 , text = "5", ).place(x = 0 , y = 160)
btn6 = tk.Button(root, height = 3 , width = 6 , text = "6", ).place(x = 60 , y = 160)
btn7 = tk.Button(root, height = 3 , width = 6 , text = "7", ).place(x = 120 , y = 160)
btn8 = tk.Button(root, height = 3 , width = 6 , text = "8", ).place(x = 180 , y = 160)
btn9 = tk.Button(root, height = 3 , width = 6 , text = "9", ).place(x = 0 , y = 220)
btn0 = tk.Button(root, height = 3 , width = 6 , text = "0", ).place(x = 60 , y = 220)
btnplus = tk.Button(root, height = 3 , width = 6, text = "+", ).place(x = 240 , y = 100)
btnminus = tk.Button(root, height = 3 , width = 6 , text = "-", ).place(x = 240 , y = 160)
btnmultiply = tk.Button(root , height = 3 , width = 6 , text = "*").place(x = 240 , y = 220)
btnequals = tk.Button(root, height = 3 , width = 6 , text = "=", ).place(x = 120 , y = 220)
btndivide = tk.Button(root, height = 3, width = 6, text = "/").place(x = 180 , y = 220)

    
root.mainloop()
```

*Note: I have just written the function to command the button with integers 1 and 2*

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: Virtually all of the code you posted is unrelated to  your problem.  You need to know how to make a button return some sort of value; this is in any tutorial on tkinter buttons.  You need to know how to take values of `1` and `2`, and make `12` from them; this is either trivial positional arithmetic, or string concatenation and conversion to integer; these are included in any tutorial on their respective topics.  Where are you stuck?  Post the problem code, not your GUI.

Answer (score 0):

You shall use something like this:

```
# globally declare the screen output variable 
scr_output = "" 
 
 
# Function to update output 
def press(num): 
    # point out the global expression variable 
    global scr_output 
 
    # concatenation of string 
    scr_output = scr_output + str(num) 
 
    # update the output by using set method 
    equation.set(scr_output)
```